# 404 Http Status by servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have created a post yesterday regarding this, but someone decided to close it. I have tried solutions from the post, it didn't work. If answer from the post could solve my issues, I won't be asking the same question again. Tried **Put servlet class in a package**, **Set servlet URL in url-pattern**, **Use domain-relative URL to reference servlet from HTML**. The thing is my registration.jsp is almost the same as my login.jsp same for the servlets as well, I dont get why it doesnt work for registration when it works for the login servlet. I also have clean and restarted my server multiples times. Didnt install tomcat into the computer just **import it thru zip files into eclipse**.

[HTTP Status 404 return by Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70844498/http-status-404-return-by-servlet)
[Servlet returns "HTTP Status 404 The requested resource (/servlet) is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731377/servlet-returns-http-status-404-the-requested-resource-servlet-is-not-availa)

**Login Servlet**

```
package net.login.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import net.login.dao.UserDAO;
import net.login.model.Users;

@WebServlet("/login")
public class UserLoginServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public @interface WebServlet {

    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UserLoginServlet() {
        super();
    }
 
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
         
        UserDAO userDao = new UserDAO();
         
        try {
            Users user = userDao.checkLogin(username, password);
            String destPage = "login.jsp";
             
            if (user != null) {
                HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("user", user);
                destPage = "home.jsp";
            } else {
                String message = "Invalid username/password";
                request.setAttribute("message", message);
            }
             
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(destPage);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
             
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

**register.jsp**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.0/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link href=”bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css” rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” />
<script type=”text/javascript” src=”bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js”></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style='text-align=center' class="container">
    <h1>New User Registration</h1>
        <form action='register' method='POST' role='form'>
        <div class='registerform'>
            <label for='username'> Username: </label>
            <input type="text" placeholder='Username' class='form-control' name='username'>
        </div>
        <div class='registerform'>  
            <label for='password'> Password: </label>
            <input type="password" class='form-control' placeholder='Password' name='password'>
        </div>
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"> Register </button>
        </form>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**UserRegisterServlet**

```
package net.login.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import net.login.dao.UserDAO;
import net.login.model.Users;

@WebServlet("/register")
public class UserRegisterServlet extends HttpServlet{
    
    
    
    public @interface WebServlet{
        
    }
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public UserRegisterServlet() {
        super();
    }
    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        //      String pathInfo = request.getPathInfo(); 
//      String[] pathParts = pathInfo.split("/");
//      String part1 = pathParts[1];
//      String part2 = pathParts[2]; 
//      
//      System.out.println(part1 + part2); //doesnt work for now since cant find /register
        
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        
        UserDAO userDAO = new UserDAO();
        
        try {
            userDAO.createUsers(username, password);
            String destPage = "register.jsp";
            
            System.out.println("Success");
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(destPage);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            
            
        }catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Just curious, would changing   `<form action='/register' method='POST' role='form'>` work for you :)   Notice the slash

Comment: Where exactly did you learn that you should be putting `public @interface WebServlet {}` in the servlet class?

Comment: didnt work btw @SMA, i tried just register or `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register` or '/register' <- this just make it point towards the rootfolder which is not what i want because there isnt any content there.

Comment: Honestly not much, I just learned from tutorials and that is what they did so I just copied them @BalusC